# How to manage installed apps (with root permission if necessary )?

Tags: android, package, uninstallation

Android users can go to the "manage application" (AKA "applications manager") screen, choose an app and make a choice of what to do there using the "App-info" screen.

I wish to make an app that allows the user to make those choices in even an easier way (maybe even batch operations).

How do I access each of the features there? Which permissions would I need and for features that are not available via the API, how could I get them via root access?

The features I'm talking about are:

1. Force stop.
2. Uninstall last updates.
3. Disable.
4. Uninstall - for this I actually know how to do it, but it needs confirmation of course:

   ```
   final Uri packageURI=Uri.parse("package:"+packageName);
   final Intent uninstallIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE,packageURI);
   ```
5. Toggle "show notificaions".
6. Clear data
7. Clear cache
8. Clear defaults. I would also like to know how to set as default and get all registered intents and their currently default apps (which will handle them).
9. View app storage usage in both external & internal storage (and cache)

If you don't know what I mean, here's a screenshot of the app-info page:

[image]

---

I've also found some interesting Android permissions that existed ever since API 1, but I can't find any examples of how to use them. Such permissions are [`CLEAR_APP_CACHE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CLEAR_APP_CACHE) , [`DELETE_PACKAGES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DELETE_PACKAGES) , and [`CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA).

What I have found is a Samsung code example (available [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples/Circle-Launcher)) that has a permission of `CLEAR_APP_CACHE`, but I can't find where they use it, if at all.

Comment: These tasks are not permitted to third-party applications, as they would be too open to abuse, and Android lacks any mechanism for a user to grant extraordinary powers to a trusted application.

Comment: so how can i make it work using root access ? i've noticed many apps that have some of those features , and even have more than them (like titanium backup , root uninstaller ,...) . how do they do it? some can even convert system apps to regular apps and then uninstall them .

Comment: @ChrisStratton I take it you are talking specifically about removal of apps? TestFlight (to name but one example) supports installation of apps from a third party site (their own).

Comment: @androiddeveloper there is the usual trick of using reflection to discover and use method calls not published as part of the developer API, but this is, to say the least, fraught with risk as each new Android version is released...

Comment: @phil aren't there adb commands for clearing the app's default ? or check if it has internal/external data ? or cache ? it could be useful for batch operations... it could be useful for different configutrations and tests

Comment: @Phil - testflight does not do the things requested here.  Anyone on a device with unknown sources enabled can use an Intent to pop up an install dialog, but the user must confirm it.  And no, reflection won't help as what is missing is the permission, not the API.

Comment: @ChrisStratton actually this is not something i was interested in, and i'm quite sure you can install an apk without any confirmation if your app is a system app or has root permission. the play store can do it, and you can do it via adb, so it's possible. what i am interested in is getting as much control of already installed apps.

Comment: One thing you'll have to deal with is that even on a rooted device, applications do not run as root, only native helpers do.  So you'll likely be stuck with a degree of indirection, either figuring out how to do things in native code running as root without android application api's, or using native code running as root to hack-install your app on the system partition in the hope that it will gain greater android permissions (but still not run as root).